# Python memory usage for integer and string

Tags: python, memory

I'm trying to understand the below snippet.

```
import sys

variable = 30
print(sys.getsizeof(variable)) #prints 28
```

If I change integer value with string

```
import sys

variable = "30"
print(sys.getsizeof(variable)) #prints 51
```

So does it means integer object makes use of less memory than string object.

Please let me know how Python makes use of memory.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Comment: "does it means integer object makes use of less memory than string object" - 28 bytes of memory is less than 51 bytes of memory, so... Although, when talking about more complex objects, be careful with this kind of reasoning because `sys.getsizeof` [doesn't take into account the memory attributed to objects the given object _refers to_].

Comment: Article on Python memory usage for variables: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609

Answer (score 4):

Yes integer object use 28 byte of memory while string object is getting bigger size of memory.